# transpose of positive matrix is positive

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

how to prove it?

I am talking about matrixes which satisfy:

$$( Ax , x ) > 0\quad \text{ for any}\quad \;x \neq 0.$$

How to prove that $A^T\;$ is also positive?

$$x^T A  x = ( x^T  A  x )^T$$

and what?

Answer (score 8):

Hint: Write the inner product as $x^T A x$ and use the fact that that expression is its own transpose (since it's a 1-by-1 matrix).

Comment: Thx, I understood!