# How to give a basis independent proof of positive definiteness of the transpose/adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

For showing the transpose (or dual, $S^T$) of positive operator, $S$, on a finite-dimensional inner product space,  is positive, I could use the following two basis *dependent* proofs:

One such is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17840/transpose-of-positive-matrix-is-positive), and another is using the fact that $S$ is self-adjoint, so it is diagonalizable. Since the transpose of a diagonal matrix is itself, the transpose of $S$ is also positive.

However, I'm looking to prove this in a basis *independent* manor. I've come up with the following:

For some finite-dim inner product space $V$, it's dual space $V^*$, and a positive operator $S$. $\dagger$ is being used to represent the adjoint for operators and complex-conjugate on field elements.

$\forall \phi \in V^*, \forall v \in V$, $\langle S^T(\phi)v, \phi(v) \rangle  = \langle \phi(S(v)), \phi(v) \rangle = (\phi(v))^{\dagger}\phi(S(v)) $.

By the Riesz representation theorem, $\exists u \in V, s.t. \forall v \in V, \phi(v) = \langle v, u \rangle$

Thus $\langle \phi(S(v)), \phi(v) \rangle = \langle S(v), \phi^{\dagger}\phi(v) \rangle = \langle S(v), \phi(v)u \rangle = (\phi(v))^{\dagger} \langle S(v), u \rangle $.

Any hints how I can proceed further, or hints to alternative methods to go about this? I don't see anything else that can be said past this point, or where the positivity of $S$ can be used.

Comment: You are overthinking it, $(S^Tx,x)=(x,Sx)=(Sx,x)>0$.

Comment: Oh wow I was. But, in general, is this why the statement you made is true ?
$\langle S^T \phi, \phi \rangle = S^T(\phi)(u) = \phi(S(u)) = \langle Su, u \rangle \ge 0$ where $u$ and $\phi$ are related as in the question.

Comment: Yes, if you think of $S:V\to V$ and $S^T:V^*\to V^*$ with the induced inner product on $V^*$. This does not make it any more general, but makes the identification of $V^*$ with $V$ via the inner product explicit.

Comment: Ah ok. You can post your comment(s) as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to think about this is to identify $V$ and $V^*$. Then the proof is slick, but it conceals the difference between $V$ and $V^*$, and the dependence of their identification on the dot product:
$$(S^Tx,x)=(x,Sx)=(Sx,x)>0.$$

In some cases, e.g. in tensor calculus and differential geometry, it is sometimes important to make this identification explicit (it corresponds to [raising and lowering indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_and_lowering_indices) in coordinate notation). To make it explicit, it is convenient to think of $S^*:V^*\to V^*$ instead of $S^T$, and write $\langle\phi,x\rangle$ instead of $\phi(x)$ for the value of $\phi\in V^*$ on $x\in V$. The $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is called the *canonical pairing*, and it saves us from writing a lot of nested parentheses. Then $S^*$ is defined by $\langle S^*\phi,x\rangle:=\langle\phi,S x\rangle$, and (a unique) functional $\phi$ is corresponded to $x$ via $\langle\phi,y\rangle=(x,y)$. There is also the induced inner product on $V^*$ with similar definition and properties. Now the calculation goes like this:
$$(S^*\phi,\phi)=\langle S^*\phi,x\rangle=\langle\phi,S x\rangle=(x,Sx)=(Sx,x)>0$$

There is a way to make this independent of an inner product. We should consider not operators on the same space, but operators *from a space to its dual* $S:V\to V^*$. They are used in tensor calculus (to contract indices), and in functional analysis, e.g. by Lions et al.

It is natural to call such operators positive definite when $\langle Sx,x\rangle>0$ for $x\neq0$. Defining $S^*$ by $\langle S^*x,y\rangle=\langle Sy,x\rangle$  we get  $S^*:V^{**}\to V^*$. Note how neither inner product, nor basis, nor any other extra structure is needed so far. Moreover, $V$ can be identified with a subspace of its double dual $V^{**}$ also *canonically*, see [injection into the double-dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Injection_into_the_double-dual). Namely, $x\mapsto\langle\cdot,x\rangle$ defines a functional on $V^*$ canonically corresponded to $x$. For finite-dimensional spaces $V$ maps onto the entire $V^{**}$. In general, when this happens the space is called [reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space). Now we recover the simplicity:
$$\langle S^*x,x\rangle=\langle Sx,x\rangle>0.$$

Comment: I appreciate the extra info. Very informative !